# AppWebUrl, HostWebUrl confusion when calling API in SP online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have a SP online instance where I want to deploy an app/add-in that lists the current user's followed sites.

The `AppWebUrl` is `https://samplesite-a98f54213c33d3.sharepoint.com/sites/dev01/MyTestApp`
The `HostWebUrl` is `https://samplesite.sharepoint.com/sites/dev01`

I just want to be able to call `/_api/social.following/my/followed(types=1)` without getting 403 or 404 errors.

Could someone show me how to do it through JSON? I've tried mix and matching URLs and haven't found the right combination yet.

My code currently looks like:

```
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
    executor.executeAsync(
        {
            url: encodeURIComponent("https://samplesite.sharepoint.com/sites/dev01/MyTestApp/_api/social.following/my/followed(types=15)"),
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: success,
            error: fail
        }
    );
```

and this gives back a 404 Not Found error. I can attest that the URL when placed directly in the browser will spit this out though:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<d:Followed m:type="Collection(SP.Social.SocialActor)" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
<d:element>
<d:AccountName m:null="true"/>
<d:ActorType m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:ActorType>
<d:CanFollow m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:CanFollow>
<d:ContentUri>https://samplesite.sharepoint.com:443/employee-centre/someSite</d:ContentUri>
<d:EmailAddress m:null="true"/>
<d:FollowedContentUri m:null="true"/>
<d:Id>8.607489c504ae441599616cad1289e796.8c76effbbd8945a1b1b2f095fd98b8d3.607489c504ae441599616cad1289e796.abe33b1c7cef41678e4092854c521fc6</d:Id>
<d:ImageUri m:null="true"/>
<d:IsFollowed m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:IsFollowed>
<d:LibraryUri m:null="true"/>
<d:Name>SomeSite</d:Name>
<d:PersonalSiteUri m:null="true"/>
<d:Status m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:Status>
<d:StatusText m:null="true"/>
<d:TagGuid m:type="Edm.Guid">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</d:TagGuid>
<d:Title m:null="true"/>
<d:Uri>https://samplesite.sharepoint.com:443/employee-centre/SomeSite</d:Uri>
</d:element>
</d:Followed>
```

Comment: Remove encodeURIComponent from the Url of the request

Comment: If I don't have `encodeURIComponent`, I get this error instead: `Invalid field or parameter requestInfo.url.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Significant edit since the social API works much differently than accessing most other information from the host environment:

Since you're still using Javascript, you're still bound by the same domain restriction; your request needs to be made against `/_api` endpoint on your appweb. Typically you will also add a reference to the hostweb that will let the `RequestExecutor` target the information from the separate host domain, but the social API works a little differently in that you can target your app web directly:

**Important**: First, ensure your App has at least `Read` permission for `User Profiles` in your manifest. You will also generally need `Read` permission across the entire `Tenant` scope (note here you'll need to be a tenant admin to install the add-in). Things will just generally "not work" and provide combinations of 403 and 404 errors if you don't have these permissions set.

To access social information in your add-in you don't even need to use the request executor library, the app web will have permission to access its own `social` endpoint directly with the relevant information you're looking for so you can just use a regular AJAX or jQuery XHR request.

If you're using jQuery, the following request from a page on your app web will provide the information you're looking for:

```
$.getJSON("/_api/social.following/my/followed(types=14)",
     function(data) { console.log(data) }
);
```

Note that for the types in the `followed` endpoint, `14` specifies "everything" (documents = `2`, sites = `4`, tags = `8`), your code was using `15`

We're just logging the response object into the console, you can inspect it further to craft your response logic.

Some further useful reading is in [the MSDN article: How to: Follow documents, sites, and tags by using the REST service in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj945068.aspx#bkmk_GetFollowed)

Comment: How do I then fit `/_api/social.following/my/followed(types=15)` in this example? Should it go into the `hostweburl` variable?

Comment: @kei major update, social API is different than typical host web reads, try the above!

Comment: I undid whatever mangling I did with my original code and based on what I've missed and what you said "First, ensure your App has at least Read permission for User Profiles in your manifest", I was able to get it working! It all came down to adding the Read permission on the User Profiles. I had the Tenant permission  set already and I thought that was good enough. I guess not. Thanks so much!